# Retrieving real-time data from Google Cloud IoT device in GET / "pull" fashion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-pubsub, esp32, google-cloud-iot

I have a need to poll for a close-to-real time reading from a serial device (using ESP32) from a web application. I am currently doing this using Particle Photons and the Particle Cloud API, and am wondering if there is a way to achieve similar using Google Cloud IoT.

From reading the documentation, it seems a common way to do this is via PubSub and then to publish to BigQuery via DataFlow or Firebase via Cloud Functions. However, to reduce pricing overhead, I am hoping to **only trigger a data exchange(s) when the device receives an external request**.

It looks like there is a way to [send commands](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/commands#iot-core-send-command-nodejs) to the IoT device - am I on the right track with this? I can't seem to find the documentation here, but after receiving a command it would use PubSub to publish to a Topic, which can trigger a Cloud Function to update Firebase?

Lastly, it also looks like there is a way to do a `GET` request to the device's `DeviceState`, but this can only be updated once per second (which might also work, though it sounds like they  generally discourage using `state` for this purpose).

If there is another low-latency, low-cost way to allow a client to poll for a real-time value from the IoT device that I've missed, please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espressif has integrated [Google's Cloud IoT Device SDK](https://github.com/espressif/esp-google-iot) which creates an authenticated bidirectional MQTT pipe between the device and IoT Core. As you've already discovered, you can send anything from the cloud to the device (it's called a "command" but it's just an MQTT payload so you can put almost anything you want in it) and vice versa (it's called "telemetry" but again it's just an MQTT payload). Once incoming messages from devices reach the cloud, pubsub can route them wherever you want. I don't know if I'd call it real-time, but latencies in a good WiFi network tend to be under a second.